# Scrape latitude and longitude of address obtained from Mapbox

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm working on my first open source project 
https://github.com/raybellwaves/cfanalytics

I want to scrape information for each gym (affiliate) from here https://map.crossfit.com/
. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618324/web-scraping-google-map-website-is-it-possible-to-scrape) on SO helped me to get the metadata for each affiliate from the map e.g. https://map.crossfit.com/getAffiliateInfo?aid=9347 (which gives address, city, state, zip and country)
but I would also like to add the latitude and longitude for each affiliate.

Am I able to scrape this information from Mapbox? It is displayed on a map so it must have the information somewhere. Otherwise I will look at obtaining the latitude and longitude from the affiliate address (using python).

Comment: There are probably easier ways of doing this. You could ask on https://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the URL the page is using to get all the affiliates `https://map.crossfit.com/getAllAffiliates.php`

That has a list containing longitude, latitude, name, aid and a number am not sure what is, for all the affiliates.

Combined with the other you had you can match the two datasets using the aid, to get the longitude and latitude for each affiliate.

Comment: Nice find. Thanks!. Would you you mind telling me how you came to find that URL? Don't think I would have ever worked that out

Comment: I opened the inspector in chrome, went to the network tab, then opened the page you linked, to see all the requests the browser was doing back to the server.  If you use the XHR tab it will not show css, javascript, images etc.